# AWK ternary operator conditional statement not working

Tags: awk

I have code that checks the contents of a variable that is created from parsing a csv file. however the code below isn't working.

```
 $3 ~ ($2 == "\"[ABCDEFGUHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]\"" ? "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$" : "\"\"$") {
  print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
}
```

sample data below

```
"ABC","A","","a" --- # This should fail because of no data in field 3
"ABC","","","a" --- # This should pass because of no data in field 2 thus it should use the else statement of empty
"ABC","A","2","a" --- # This should pass because of data in field 2 and 3
```

however whats actually happening is the second sample that should pass is failing and I cant for the life of me work out why

Comment: You used `$2==`, yet the content after `==` seems a regex. If you want to use regex, change to `~` instead.

Comment: yes it works with either but the outcome for the problem I having is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this, see if it's working:

```
$3 ~ ($2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/ ? "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$" : "\"\"$") {
  print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
}
```

To be more exact, you can further change to `$2 ~ /^"[A-Z]"$/`.

But with that `print` line you can't really see the differences.
You can change it to:

```
print "Line: " FNR "\t15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
```

Then you will see the difference.

**Update**:
We misunderstood your meaing,
if *fail* means print, and *pass* to ignore, then this is what you wanted:

```
$3 ~ ($2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/ ? "\"\"$" : "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$") {
  print "Line: " FNR "\t15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
}
```

Change the position of two branches will do.

Comment: no this doesn't work either its still showing the print line if the $2 and $3 is empty whereas it should be showing nothing

Comment: so pass would mean that the program doesn't print the 15th field invalid line

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your script, it seems to be a bit awkward. Let's translate what you have done.

**Note:** I assume that you called awk with `awk -F, -f file.awk inputfile`

1. **`$3 ~ expr`:** This line attempts to match field 3 to the extended regular expression represented by `expr`.
2. **`($2 == "\"[ABCDEFGUHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]\"" ? "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$" : "\"\"$")`:** The used expression `expr` in the above ERE is a ternary operation:

   - **`$2 == "\"[ABCDEFGUHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]\""`:** if field 2 **equals** the string `"[ABCDEFGUHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"` then
   - **`^\"[[:digit:]]\"$"`:** match field 3 to the ERE `^"[[:digit:]]"$`, otherwise
   - **`"\"\"$"`:** otherwise match the empty string `""`.

The problem lays in the conditional of the ternary operator, which should be `$2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/` instead of the equality operator.

```
$3 ~ ($2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/ ? "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$" : "\"\"$") {
  print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
}
```

This might be more readable however:

```
($2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/ && $3 ~ /^"[[:digit:]]"$/) || 
  ($2 !~ /"[A-Z]"/ && $3 ~ /^""$/) { 
     print "15th field invalid-OFFENCE FILE"
}
```

---

```
$ awk -F, '($2 ~ /"[A-Z]"/ ? "^\"[[:digit:]]\"$" : "\"\"$")' file
"ABC","","","a"
"ABC","A","2","a"
```

Comment: I was using the [[ABCDEFGUHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ] to prevent  accidental match of a non locale character because of the multitude of matches that can occur in UTF 8 charset. I will check to see if your answer works though :)

Comment: after checking neither option seems to have worked it still following the wrong  regex

Comment: @jordanb111 how are you invoking your `awk` command. Do you specify `FS=","`?

Comment: @jordanb111 I have added my output of the command to the post. I believe it is correct.

Comment: so im parsing the the csv file with    ` awk -F, '
     BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }
     NF!=17 { print "incorrect   amount    of fields-OFFFENCE FILE";}`

Comment: @jordanb111 `awk` won't match other characters other than `A` to `Z`, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228789/5403468) for details.  Oh you are already using `-F,`, that's the right way. However when you're using `FPAT`, then be careful to check each field has `"` or not.

Comment: the comma separating work with my code as I have the program already successfully validating 17 other fields it just this if statement that's not working i also have other ternary statements working using the method shown in my post and they work as intended