# How does setlocale() work on Windows?

Tags: php, locale

Developing a multilingual application I'd like to output locale-correct numbers and dates. Testing on Win7 I'm failing with both:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu', 'de', 'ge', 'German_Germany.1251');
var_dump(localeconv());
```

Shows that the decimal character is . but should be , for German.

```
$f = 3.14;
echo($f);
```

Confirms 3.14 as output.

Regardless what I've tried for setting the locale I didn't have success. Similar results apply with `number_format()`. It does however work for dates, e.g. month names.

What is the correct way to `setlocale()` on Windows/ CLI?

Comment: Answered many times before, for ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995953/php-setlocale-in-windows-7

Comment: Don't see how that is supposed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a known problem with PHP since 5.3: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65230

`setlocale()` should be avoided in favor of `NumberFormatter` whenever possible.